# sass how use a @for in a @mixin

Tags: css, loops, sass, mixins, preprocessor

I using sass to make a grid, i am using the logic bellow to define the columns in many screens and sizes.

```
@each $breakpoint, $container-size in $grid-containers {    
    @include breakpoint($breakpoint){
        @for $column from 1 through $grid-columns { /* This loop will define the columns */
            @if map-get($grid-breakpoints, $breakpoint) != none{
                .col-#{$breakpoint}-#{$column} {
                    flex-basis: percentage($column / $grid-columns);
                    padding-left: $grid-gutter;
                    padding-right: $grid-gutter;
                }
            } 
            @else {
                .col-#{$column} {
                    flex-basis: percentage($column / $grid-columns);
                    padding-left: $grid-gutter;
                    padding-right: $grid-gutter;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now i wanna transform this code into a mixin and define the column like this:

```
@include column-rule(.col) {
   flex-basis: percentage($column / $grid-columns); /* $column is undefined */
   padding-left: $grid-gutter;
   padding-right: $grid-gutter;
}

/* Another sample */
@include column-rule(.order) {
    order: $column; /* $column is undefined */
}
```

But as you can see i need use variable $column who was define into a loop. I can get the value of $column using a mixin?